# How to initialize LPBOOL? Win32 Api in Kotlin Native

Tags: winapi, kotlin, compiler-errors, native, kotlin-native

How do I call this in Kotlin Native

```
    val result = CopyFileExA(
                          oldFile,
                          newFile,
                          null,
                          null,
                          false,
                          COPY_FILE_FAIL_IF_EXISTS
                         )
```

while `false` is not accepted as `LPBOOL`? How do I initialize LPBOOL to be used in Kotlin native interface?

I am getting the following error :

> the boolean literal does not conform to the expected type
>
> LPBOOL? /* = CPointer
>   */>? */ false,

Comment: `LPBOOL` is a pointer to a `BOOL` variable (`BOOL*`). I don't know what Kotlin is, but in C/C++ this call would like like this: `BOOL cancel = FALSE; BOOL result = CopyFileExA(oldFile, newFile, NULL, NULL, &cancel, COPY_FILE_FAIL_IF_EXISTS);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the question that is already in [github from @olonho](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/issues/2042#issuecomment-420526537)

You need to alloc a variable using the especial platform types [NativePlacement](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/51faa779f685f6149a0e53d3d585d3533ba2d435/INTEROP.md#memory-allocation)

```
import kotlinx.cinterop.*
import platform.windows.*

val buffer = nativeHeap.allocArray<ByteVar>(size)
<use buffer>
nativeHeap.free(buffer)
```

but for avoid the free call or unallocated memory you can use the memScoped

```
val fileSize = memScoped {
  val statBuf = alloc<statStruct>()
  val error = stat("/", statBuf.ptr)
  statBuf.st_size
}
```

important, the pointer binding will be with statBuf.ptr, then your code will be:

```
    memScoped {
      val oldFile = "README.md"
      val newFile = "${oldFile}.cp"
      val bool = alloc<BOOLVar>()
      bool.value = FALSE

      val result = CopyFileExA(
              oldFile,
              newFile,
              null,
              null,
              bool.ptr,
              COPY_FILE_FAIL_IF_EXISTS
      )
    }
```

This have to be similar if you need to binding with a objective-c library.